# Find boundaries of 2d array presented with indexes

Tags: algorithm, grid

I know this question looks like some other questions. But I think that because of a small difference, this is a completely different problem than what I can find on the rest of Stackoverflow.

So my problem is that I'm creating some small board game and I want to move to all directions, so up, down, left and right. When I do this, I have to know what my boundary is for each direction. I would like to have some generic thing for this, so that if I have any number and I would go in any direction. I could calculate what the border cell is, e.g. I start from 11 and want to go left, so I should get as border number 9. If I start from 6 and I want to go down, I would get 14 as my border number.

This is they way I represent my board. So I do it in a one-dimensional array with the numbers indexes+1 representing where they are on the board.

```
+--+--+--+--+
|1 |2 |3 |4 |
+--+--+--+--+
|5 |6 |7 |8 |
+--+--+--+--+
|9 |10|11|12|
+--+--+--+--+
|13|14|15|16|
+--+--+--+--+
```

Anyone who has any experience with this? Who knows a simple way on how to get this border number?

Thank you

Comment: It seems like it would be simpler to use a two-dimensional array. It doesn't matter if a 1d array is simpler for the computer to allocate if it makes the programmer's job harder.

Comment: I know, but this representations makes it much simpler in the rest of the program. Otherwise, I would use a two-dimensional array of course.

Answer (score 0):

Convert from 1D coordinates to 2D coordinates, alter the x and y values as needed, then convert back to 1D coordinates.

```
function boundary(idx, direction){

    rows = 4;
    cols = 4;

    idx -= 1;

    x = idx % cols;
    y = int(Math.floor(idx / cols));

    if (direction == "left"){
        x = 0;
    }
    else if (direction == "right"){
        x = cols-1;
    }
    else if (direction == "up"){
        y = 0;
    }
    else if (direction == "down"){
        y = rows-1;
    }

    return cols * y + x + 1;
}
```

Comment: This wasn't really a correct answer for my problem, because if I do the calculation with some values on the border, I get a wrong result. But this helped me with my logic. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oops, I thought you started counting from zero, not one. edited. If you are still getting a wrong result, please let me know the index, direction, expected result, and actual result.